# .net c# Livecharts only show one series on tooltip x&y value

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, livecharts

I have been trying to create a graph in .net C# with the library: https://v0.lvcharts.com/
I have quite a few different series on my graph and all with different points per x value. As seen below this is the current tooltip on hover.

What i need is to only display the X value: 00:07 & the Series 'Measured Temperature'. I do not want to show any of these other series on my tooltip. If i use the SelectionMode.OnlySender it does not show the X value: 00:07 which is quite important since graphs can be over 24 hours long..... Because otherwise it would be quite tricky to find out at which time you are specifically looking...

Does anyone know how to only show 1 series with Y&X value? Not any other series...
The project is made in WinForms c# .NET

[image: currentTooltip]

Comment: Can you provide some of the code to illustrate what you've tried?

Comment: @Noel i only tried the function provided by livecharts: `DefaultTooltip tooltip = new DefaultTooltip { SelectionMode = TooltipSelectionMode.OnlySender, ShowTitle = true, ShowSeries = false };` and solution provided below. My goal is to have all graphics visible on the graph, only have the tooltip hide all fields except the one that is being hoverd on. The OnlySender tooltip is given solution by livecharts for this, sadly this also removes the X value in the tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the IsVisible property in your element of graph collection:

```
SeriesCollection[i].IsVisible = false;
```

i - is the index of the element in the collection

If it looked like creating a pre-hidden element:

```
SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection
            {
                new LineSeries
                {
                    Title = "Series 1",
                    Values = new ChartValues<double> { 4, 6, 5, 2 ,4 }
                    IsVisible= false; // this one
                }
            };
```

Or is your goal to leave all the graphics in place, but only hide all the fields in the ToolTip except the one you hovered over?

Comment: Hey, yhea the visual elements, like the lines are still required to be visible in the graph. Only not visible on the ToolTip. Basically need the OnlySender ToolTip for y value (as it provides with OnlySender) But also the X value.